# Relationship between Entities with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join, relationship, entities

Supposing I want to have users who have no posts in an application, usually with sql I write something like this:

```
SELECT p.* FROM users u
LEFT JOIN posts p on u.user_id=p.user_id;
```

Now I'm wondering, if I wanted to take all posts for single user from application, including also those who don't have any posts, it would go something like this:

```
class User {

   private int $id;

   public function __construct(int $id)
   {
     $this->id = $id;
   }

   public function posts() : Generator
   {
     $sql = 'SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE user_id=' . $this->id;

     foreach(Db::fetchObject($sql) as $post){
       if(!$post->post_id) continue; // This assure inner join without this is left join?
       yeld new Post($post->post_id);
     };
   }
}
```

Now the if on the foreach ensures the inner join because it eliminates empty results and basically if one loops all users, it won't get users who don't have any posts. But if I wanted to have users who don't have posts, would I just remove the if in the foreach loop and expect an exception that would then return null or 0 as a result? Or do something else need to be done?

I know you have to bind the fecthObject but I've simplified the code a bit, since I'm interested in understanding how to convert queries into objects and maintain relationships, there's a book about that that explains how to bind between data domain to one object?

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  What's your question?  'Now the if on the foreach ensures the inner join because it eliminates empty results' ... but there isn't an inner join in your code

Comment: If this is your question 'I want to have users who have no posts' then you're probably looking for some SQL like this: `SELECT u.* FROM users u LEFT JOIN posts p ON u.user_id = p.user_id WHERE p.user_id IS NULL`

Comment: Yeah the question is: if I don't use a if, I'll have a left join, right?

Comment: As it stands, your code doesn't show any kind of join

Comment: @RobEyre I don't want posts that not belongs to anyone and to do what you wrote I can use a Right Join or reversing tables in LEFT JOIN. I want all User despite they have or not posts.

Comment: Presuming `post_id` is the primary key from your `posts` table, then `$post->post_id` will always be non-zero, so the `continue;` statement will never execute.  You could remove that whole `if` statement and it would make no difference to what your code does.  At the moment, you're selecting all the posts related to a specific user, there are no joins involved.

Comment: @RobEyre If I use a user_id that has no post I'll get no posts so the continue is useful. The assuming is that I copied a sot of pseudocode to understand , anyway the only thing I have to do is put the if outside the loop.

Comment: @RobEyre Iwe use join to have all posts by a single id of user ok? My query gets back all posts of a user by its id. If I use a foreach and pass all user on a external client, it will be the same as a join.

Comment: What does `Db::fetchObject($sql)` return when there are no matching rows from your query?  If it's an empty array (or Iterable) then no need for your `if`, as the loop will never execute.  If it returns something else, then I see the need for it, but that's an unusual pattern.